# 1 word for books, videos, podcasts, speeches, etc. (learning materials)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, hypernyms

Do you have any suggestions? I have some already in my list which I am still not satisfied yet:

- medium/media
- asset/assets
- publication/publications
- resource/resources
- source/sources

Answer (score 2):

One of the senses of ***content*** is a pretty close match.

> **1.4** Information made available by a website or other electronic medium.
>        
> *‘online content providers’*
> <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/content)</sub>

From a different source (which expands *content* beyond online mediums):

> In publishing, art, and communication, **content** is the information and experiences that are directed toward an end-user or audience. ... Content can be delivered via many different media including the Internet, cinema, television, radio, smartphones, audio CDs, books, e-books, magazines, and live events, such as speeches, conferences, and stage performances.
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_(media))</sub>

Comment: Thanks @jxh for the suggestion. I am looking for a word that would cover both digital and physical content.

Comment: @Thriveristα: *Content* is not restricted to online mediums. I expanded the Wikipedia quote to indicate that.

Comment: @Thriveristα *I am looking for a word that would cover both digital and physical content.* "Content" does that - it expresses a general set of contents of any sort of anything.

Comment: Ordinary people do not refer to their books, videos, etc. as content any more than they refer to them as media, so if the aim is to find a word that an ordinary user would perceive as natural (rather than a part of a jargon), then *content* is not much of an improvement over *media*.

Comment: @jsw29: *Media* seems more technical, because it actually refers to the delivery channels of information, and not the information itself. I suggest *content* as a fairly contemporary way to refer to the material being provided to and obtained from various sources.

Comment: @jsw29: For example, consider [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_start=1985&year_end=2019&corpus=26&content=video+content%2Cvideo+media&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvideo%20content%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvideo%20media%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

After comments under my original answer that clarify the question, I have had to change my answer.

---

The context for this is provided in the question [Different word for “idea” in book, videos, articles, podcasts, movies, music, artwork, etc.?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/540733/291924)

In that question, it asks for a different word for *idea*. As such, this answer and that answer are in a kind of lockstep. In that question, I proposed that the alternate word for *idea* should be *information*.

As such, the the word to describe the medium that conveys information is [**source**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/source):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 b (3)** : one that supplies information

As such, the phrases in the question can be paraphrased as follows:

- Add your *information* ***source***.
- Find your *information* ***source***.

---

Note that *source* was considered and rejected when this question was posed. However, it's only not entirely idiomatic when thinking of an *idea source*, where *idea* was the other word making up a resultant phrase. If the other word is *information*, then *information source* is completely idiomatic and common.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion. I think "aid" matches the meaning but I feel like it doesn't fit the context.

Comment: @Thriveristα What is the context you're thinking of, if not a learning aid? Or let me put it another way. What's an example of such a thing that is *not* a learning aid? (Or educational aid or entertainment aid?)

Comment: My bad not elaborate. You could read also one [other of my questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540733/different-word-for-idea-in-book-videos-articles-podcasts-movies-music-ar) to clarify the context. In general, the system has different types of content (aid). Each content has different ideas. Now, if I say "let's discuss an idea from an aid", it sounds a bit weird. :)

Comment: @Thriveristα I looked at your other question. I still think my suggestion makes sense. Rather than *idea*, you would have *knowledge* (which would be the answer to that question), and *aid* would be the corresponding word here. In short, it wouldn't be **idea medium** but **knowledge aid**. Still, it's confusing that this question doesn't have the context it needs within the question itself—or that the context is still in flux, pending the answer to the other question …

Comment: @Thriveristα I have updated my answer—in parallel with providing an answer to the other question. I do not believe that either question can be fully asked (or answered) without referring to the other. But to be fair to anybody else contributing to these questions, you should add a reference to the other question to this question—and vice versa—as well as explaining the type of words you want to use in combination in a single phrase. (In my "combined" answer I have now used **information source**.)

Comment: @Thriveristα Last, "let's discuss *information* from a *source*" sounds fine, inasmuch as that particular sentence construction can be made to sound okay. (I don't think any combination of any two words in those positions can sound completely normal.)

Comment: I have updated my question to include the context. `source` is also one of my selections, so I will definitely consider it. 

> If the other word is information, then `information source` is completely idiomatic and common.
But I feel line `information source` refers to a source of information instead of an information that belongs to the source.

Comment: @Thriveristα You're right. When you say *information source*, it's the source you're talking about. But when if you say *source information*, you're talking about the information that belongs to the source.

Answer (score 0):

How about **stuff**? From Lexico:

> **[stuff](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stuff)**: Matter, material, articles, or activities of a specified or indeterminate kind that are being referred to, indicated, or implied.

You could use **stuff** to describe one's books, videos, articles, podcasts, movies, music, artwork, etc.

You could say, "Add your **stuff**", "Find your **stuff**", "My **stuff**", etc.

**Stuff** would encompass physical and digital content.

Comment: thanks for your comment. "Stuff" makes a lot of sense in covering the content, but it sounds to me a bit "trivial". But its the nice suggestion, I'll put it in the list :)

Comment: @Thriveristα, it begins to look like you are imposing two contradictory constraints on the term you are seeking: in the question you say that you don't want the word to be too 'technical', but now you also say that you don't want it to be 'trivial'. The first requirement seems to amount to its not being a part of a jargon, the second seems to amount to its being a part of a jargon.

Answer (score -1):

My consideration: `asset`.
Definition of `asset`: a useful or valuable thing or person.

Now, let's break it down. `asset` is not a less of jargon than `medium` or `content`, but it is a common word, which people are using in a day to day life. Also, given the system is about storing valuable media, sharing its idea, I think `asset` would signify a bit of the meaning there, like treating these media like assets.

Comment: The connotation of *asset* is one that provides some sort of net-positive value, and there is an associated antonym, *liability*. So using *asset* may unfairly bias the ideas/materials/information toward some direction that would be considered "positive". This works, though, if you are wanting to impart the concept of something that needs to be guarded or protected.

Comment: Although, it is true that *asset* can, according to dictionary definitions, be used for anything that has any kind of value, the term is most often used for things that have substantial commercial value, so some people may find it odd to to hear it used for something that may have, commercially, only nominal value. Of the terms listed here, I would 'vote' for *materials*.

Comment: @jsw29 you had a good point because I was also afraid of the same thing. Do you mean `material` in place of `medium`? Then what would you suggest for the `idea` of `materials`?